# How to store different themes with assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am hoping someone can explain **how I can do the following with and without asset pipline** in rails.

I have 3 themes that I need to use in a single rails application.

Each theme currently has the following structure:

```
/css/..
/fonts/..
/images/..
/js/..
```

I may add more themes in the future, so I would think it would be best to have each theme in its own folder, not spread around.

**Can I use asset pipline with this theme requirement?**

If not, how can I do it w/o using asset pipeline?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I recommend you to use the asset pipeline as it improves the web application static assets loading performance by precompilation and setting caching headers for you.

For three themes viz. theme1, theme2, and theme3 this is what I'd do:-

- Create individual layouts called `theme1.html.erb`, `theme2.html.erb`, and `theme3.html.erb` within the `app/views/layouts` directory.
- Create stylesheets called `theme1.scss`, `theme2.scss`, and `theme3.scss` within the `app/assets/stylesheets` directory.
- Create JS files called `theme1.js`, `theme2.js`, and `theme3.js` within the `app/assets/javascripts` directory.
- Create subdirectories called `theme1`, `theme2`, and `theme3` within the `app/assets/images` directory.
- You can add the fonts directly into the stylesheets directory as they'll most probably be unique for every theme.
- Reference the images using asset pipeline helpers as you'd do normally do after prepending the relative directory path for that theme in context to the `app/assets/images` directory before the image name.
- Also, do not forget to import/require the files or add them to the asset compilation path within `config/initializers/asset.rb` file.